# Как более правильно будет писаться код, когда он будет написан кучно или по отдельным функциям? PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода, pyqt5, рефакторинг

Вопрос заключается в следующем какой из этих двух примеров будет более читаемый. Ну или как лучше будет писать код, отдельно как в первом варианте или все в кучу( в плане дополнение к коду все в одну функцию)

**ПРИМЕР 1**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
class mainwidow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mainwidwos()
        self.printy()
    def mainwidwos(self):
        self.windows = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()
        x_randge_windows =self.windows.width() - 100
        y_randge_windows =self.windows.height() - 100
        self.setFixedSize(x_randge_windows, y_randge_windows)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test Creater 2.0')
        self.show()
        self.center()
    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())
    def printy(self):
        self.hbox = QGridLayout(self)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar()
        self.opentestfile = QAction('Открыть', self)
        self.closefile = QAction('Закрыть программу', self)
        self.closefile.triggered.connect(lambda: self.close())
        self.fileMenu_file = self.menubar.addMenu('File')
        self.fileMenu_file.addAction(self.opentestfile)
        self.fileMenu_file.addAction(self.closefile)
        self.Test_select = QAction('Тест с выбором', self)
        self.fileMenu_Edit = self.menubar.addMenu('Тесты')
        self.fileMenu_Edit.addAction(self.Test_select)
        self.hbox.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = mainwidow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**ПРИМЕР 2**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
class mainwidow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mainwidwos()
    def mainwidwos(self):
        self.windows = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()
        x_randge_windows =self.windows.width() - 100
        y_randge_windows =self.windows.height() - 100
        self.setFixedSize(x_randge_windows, y_randge_windows)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test Creater 2.0')
        self.show()
        self.center()
        self.hbox = QGridLayout(self)
        self.menubar = QMenuBar()
        self.opentestfile = QAction('Открыть', self)
        self.closefile = QAction('Закрыть программу', self)
        self.closefile.triggered.connect(lambda: self.close())
        self.fileMenu_file = self.menubar.addMenu('File')
        self.fileMenu_file.addAction(self.opentestfile)
        self.fileMenu_file.addAction(self.closefile)
        self.Test_select = QAction('Тест с выбором', self)
        self.fileMenu_Edit = self.menubar.addMenu('Тесты')
        self.fileMenu_Edit.addAction(self.Test_select)
        self.hbox.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())
if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = mainwidow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Всё равно оба не соответствуют требованиям pep8

Comment: Обратите внимание вот на какой момент, `QApplication`, `QDesktopWidget`, `QAction`, `QMenuBar`, `QGridLayout`, каждый из перечисленных объектов - класс. И каждый из этих классов начинается с большой буквы. По тому что все классы в Python принято писать с большой буквы CamelCase'ом. Пусть Ваши классы будут как эти :)

Comment: "кучно" - звучит звучно =D
А если серьезно, то из советов нулевого уровня - одна функция не больше  страницы кода
А так да - читайте PEP8 в русскоязычном интернете